# php bulk video Upload to ftp script

Tags: php

In my application i have to upload more than 100 videos to ftp folder daily basis, right now i am doing this manually from filezilla ftp client. 
     **Please suggest me any automated script using php to do this .**

Your Suggestions are welcome .

Best Regards, 
Bakul Damodariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have php on your computer installed (if you want to use php scripting)

You can scan a dir using `glob()` or your prefered directory iterator, filter the files you want to upload into an array, and use php's curl functions to upload it:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

If you want it to be completely automatic you could set the task scheduler (if you are on windows, or a similar tool if you are on another OS ) to run the script from php's command line.

Comment: this comment seems useful to me .....

Comment: Im glad to guide you on the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use c panel (control panel) of web hosting.

it is efficient and fast way to upload video on server.